# Integrate FPDI with TCPDF in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, tcpdf, fpdi

I am using TCPDF successfully with codeigniter. Now I want to use FPDI. So I can merge PDFs. How do I do that? As an example I found this: http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/demos/tcpdf-demo/

When I run this class, codeigniter is dead. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. I tried to load the fpdf, fpdi libraries and CI just went dead. So, I had to uncomment those lines from the controller that made any references to the fpdf, fpdi libraries. restart apache and yes, CI was back on track.

To be able to use the FPDI, the following link gave me the answers that I was looking for.

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/91996/